# Put output of a command in a variable GoCD

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, go-cd

I try to create a variable with the version of a project in a GoCD job.

My project is built with maven. The version of the project is set on the pom.xml file (present on the git repository).

Maven allow to retrieve the version of the project with command :

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version
```

So I tried to put the output of this command in a linux variable :

```
my_version=${mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version}
```

And then use it to push the project on a docker repository :

```
docker push my_project:$my_version
```

The problem is that GoCD seems to have his own interpreter (see https://docs.gocd.org/current/faq/dev_use_current_revision_in_build.html ).To use a variable, I must do something like this :

```
sh -c docker push my_project:$my_version
```

But I can't find a way to set a linux variable.

Is it something that is ok to do with GoCD ? What is the right way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GoCD doesn't maintain a single shell session for the entire job. So even if you use `sh export MY_VERSION=...` and try to use that in the next task within the same job it will not work as expected.

To solve this problem the best way is to wrap the entire set of commands you want to perform within a shell script and execute that shell script as a task. Given the entire shell script would be executed within a single shell instance anything variable you define can be used.

Comment: It's pretty much what I feared. I found that unmaintainable to have shell scripts bundled in the GoCD Agent. It means I must put a shell script on it for each use case...

Comment: As a general convention, we have a separate repo or a folder within each repo called "ops" which contains all these scripts and we use that wire up tasks in GoCD. May be that approach might help you.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted GoCD to contain all informations about the build process. Anyway, thank you for your answere :-)

Comment: Glad to be of help. Generally it's considered an anti-pattern to make your build scripts dependent on the tool used for the build process. Having the actual build steps outside and using the tool to just orchestrate the process can ease things on the long run if you want to migrate to some other tool.

Comment: It's a good point ! But since you can easily import/export gocd templates I found very convenient to have all commands on a single location.